# Why is my JavaFX output not showing a VBox when I click a button?

Tags: javafx

I am writing a code where you choose an option from a list and when you click the button, it should show up. When you click the button, nothing happens.

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class BulletJournal extends Application {
 private double[] studyHours;
 private int days;
 private ArrayList < Person > users = new ArrayList < > ();
 private Person user;
 private Label errorMessage;
 private Button enterUser;
 private VBox in ;
 private VBox spreadV = new VBox();

 public static void main() {
  launch();
 }

 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  Person user = new Person("Alyssa");
  double[] studyHours = {
   3.1,
   4.5,
   4.6,
   4.6
  };
  user.setStudyHours(studyHours);
  Event[] events = {
   new Event("Work", 12, 06, 2020),
   new Event("Work", 13, 06, 2020),
   new Event("Work", 14, 06, 2020)
  };
  user.setEvents(events);
  String[] fitness = {
   "Cardio",
   "Cardio",
   "Cardio and Abs"
  };
  user.setFitness(fitness);
  String[] breakfasts = {
   "Oatmeal",
   "English Muffin",
   "Toast",
   "Cereal"
  };
  user.setBreakfastOptions(breakfasts);
  String[] lunches = {
   "Bagel",
   "Grain Bowl",
   "Smoothie",
   "Salad"
  };
  user.setLunchOptions(lunches);
  String[] dinners = {
   "Cauliflower",
   "Veggie Burger",
   "Spring Rolls",
   "Pasta"
  };
  user.setDinnerOptions(dinners);

  ComboBox < String > spreads = new ComboBox < String > ();
  spreads.getItems().addAll("Calendar", "Study Tracker", "Fitness Tracker", "Meal Plan", "Edit User Info");

  Button select = new Button("Open Spread");

  select.setOnAction(event -> {
   String choiceS = spreads.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

   if (choiceS.equals("Calendar")) {
    spreadV = new VBox(Calendar.outPut(user));
   } else if (choiceS.equals("Study Tracker")) {
    spreadV = new VBox(StudyTracker.outPut(user));
   } else if (choiceS.equals("Fitness Tracker")) {
    spreadV = new VBox(FitnessTracker.outPut(user));
   } else if (choiceS.equals("Meal Plan")) {
    spreadV = new VBox(MealPlan.outPut(user));
   } else {
    spreadV = new VBox(Edit.outPut(user));
   }

  });

  HBox h2 = new HBox(10, spreads);
  VBox v2 = new VBox(10, h2, select);

  VBox finalV = new VBox(10, v2, spreadV);

  Scene scene = new Scene(finalV);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.show();
 }
}
```

When you click on the button that is supposed to bring you to your choice, nothing happens. Typically I do not have this issue.
Thank you in advance for your help. This is my final project and I have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Could you please add your Person class?  
I'd suggest to add your Calendar, StudyTracker, FitnessTracker, MealPlan and Edit too...

Comment: I think that if you overwrite reference to spreadV like that it won't be treated as change of finalV children. Old empty VBox will still be present in finalV children. Try removing old one and adding new one instead.

Comment: All you do is create a new `VBox`; you never add it to the scene graph anywhere.

Comment: You are asking for help in debugging your code. The easiest way for me to debug your code is by running it and reproducing your problem. I can't do that with the code you posted because you have not provided a [mcve]. I suggest you [edit] your question and post code that reproduces your problem and which I can copy and run on my computer. Note that you don't have to post all your code, Just post code that reproduces your problem.